# How to maintain spinal decompression?

Tags: spine

Did some experiments on my height:

- 167cm after heavy squats
- 170cm after a short walk
- 175cm after hanging on a bar
- 176cm after hanging on a bar with weights

After hanging, I'm taller than normally, but just after a few minutes of walking my height goes back to 170 centimetres. 6 cm are like slightly more than 2 inches.

I wanna know how to keep a decompressed spine for longer after doing dead hangs. With shoes on and a decompressed spine I'm an average height person and a shoter than average person...kind of sucks that the spinal decompression doesn't last much.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have found no way to decrease spinal compression or the speed at which it happens to maintain a decompressed spine for longer.  The spine usually returns from decompressed to partially compressed in a matter of a few minutes.

But I have found some ways to stretch the spine everywhere without needing a pull up bar or dip station.

Side bends and standing toe touch poses proved incredibly effective at decompressing the spine, from 170 centimetres to 173 centimetres after one single toe touch stretch for two seconds.

[image]

Side bends had the same effect but took longer to get the same stretch, about 10 seconds per side to reach 3 centimetres.  Apparently holding those stretches for longer in hope to reach 176 centimetres does not work, probably because it only stretches the lower portion of the spine and not the thorax. And probably the dead hang with weights also stretches other ligaments.

I believe crunching exercises can stretch the spine too, but they are not really feasible when just taking a walk with friends.